# Gazebo doesn't give the option for saving a world

Tags: ros, gazebo, world, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, ROS Community!

I use Jade distribution, Gazebo 5.1.0 version, Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

When I add some objects `Insert` tab of Gazebo and try to save the world after, I cant do it. The empty window `Save World` popped up without any options.

[image: image description]

Yesterday, I was struggling with this problem too. When I was stopping gazebo process by terminal or GUI, the world objects were deleted too. It means gazebo was launched (`rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo`) with empty scene every times.

I decided to update packages by `sudo apt-get update` command, because I suggested the bug can belong to ubuntu. So, I updated them successfully.

Today, I get the empty `Save World` window again, but objects are saved even when I stop gazebo process with this notification:

```
albina@alb91:~/catkin_ws/src$ rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo
/opt/ros/jade/lib/gazebo_ros/gazebo: 30: kill: invalid signal number or name: SIGINT
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226918/gazebo-doesn%27t-give-the-option-for-saving-a-world/) by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2016-02-17**:
I had some problems with gazebo 5 gui when I was trying to import some images for the building editor. So I moved to gazebo6.

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2016-02-18**:
Thank you )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you can write a launch file to include models and world. You can put model in accurate position by writing it.
[An example](http://answers.ros.org/question/226175/fail-to-control-two-husky-robots-in-gazebo/). It is not complicated to do that.

---

Originally posted by [Devin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25894/devin/) with karma: 62 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2016-02-18**:
Yes, I will follow your advice. Thank you